# Dajngo: refreshing page resubmit last form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a view like:

```
def some_view(request, page_url):
    form = UserTicketForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            ticket_text = request.POST.get('ticket_text')
    data = dict(
        form=UserTicketForm,
    )

    return render(request, 'front/some_page.html', data)
```

and in HTML page it has:

```
{% csrf_token %}
{% bootstrap_form form %}
{% block submit %}
    <div class="button_holder">
    <button type="submit" name="register-submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="send">
    submit
    </button>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

each time I refresh the page, it resubmits the last submitted form. how can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to a different url after the form is submitted and saved

```
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            ticket_text = request.POST.get('ticket_text')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_url'))
```

Comment: it worked. but isn't there any other solutions for this issue?

Comment: It's standard practice to redirect after a successful form submission. Otherwise you get resubmits on page refresh. This is true of all form submissions, not just django.

Answer (score 0):

Write Like this

```
 def some_view(request, page_url):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserTicketForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
                ticket_text = request.POST.get('ticket_text')
        data = dict(
            form=UserTicketForm,
        )
    
        return render(request, 'front/some_page.html', data)
```